# How to put Image beside text

Tags: html, css

I have to put an image beside the text, but the text is going under the image (Refer below)

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

here is the what I coded:

```
.Har {
    display:inline;
}
.Har * {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
<div class="Har">
 <img alt="" src="http://imagd/m/1/df2dfe55-a8e2-488d-9e23-ea0c14c04236.png"><span>Choose your car for a low weekly rate </span></div>
```

Comment: Take a look at different layout modes and learn how float, block, inline, etc. work. Your text is wrapping below the image because it’s just long text is all.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage flex box like I did below

```css
.Har {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.Har span {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Har">
  <img alt="" src="http://imagd/m/1/df2dfe55-a8e2-488d-9e23-ea0c14c04236.png">
  <span>Choose your car for a low weekly rate </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [flexbox.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png">
</img>
<p>This is my text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to wrap below the image when it gets long enough, you can use `float`:

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="Har">
 <img alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
 <span>Choose your car for a low weekly rate. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog.  Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.  Choose your car for a low weekly rate. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog.  Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.  Choose your car for a low weekly rate. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog.  Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.</span></div>
```

Or if you prefer that the text never wrap below the image, you can use `flexbox`:

```css
.Har {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  margin-right: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="Har">
 <img alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
 <span>Choose your car for a low weekly rate. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog.  Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.  Choose your car for a low weekly rate. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog.  Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.  Choose your car for a low weekly rate. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog.  Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.</span></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can try is wrapping both HTML tags in divs and provide your margins and padding to the classes.